# Facebook get access Token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to get a **"access token"** using Facebook Graph API. I have app ID, the username and password of the user. Just i need to get the access token so that i may be able to access news feed,.... and others.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay so you need to get the `access_token` of a user in JavaScript. Here you go:

1. Start reading the [JavaScript SDK documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)
2. Something like the below will get you started:

   ```
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
       FB.init({
           appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
           channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
           status     : true, // check login status
           cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
           xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
       });
       // this shouldn't be called directly, but instead should be initiated with a user click event
       FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
               console.log('Access Token: ' + response.authResponse.accessToken);
           } else {
               console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
           }
       });

   };

   // Load the SDK Asynchronously
   (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
   </script>
   ```
3. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/):

   > Calling FB.login results in the JS SDK attempting to open a popup
   >   window. As such, this method should only be called after a user click
   >   event, otherwise the popup window will be blocked by most browsers.
4. **NEVER** ***EVER*** ask for the user password nor give it to **ANY** application if it asks you! and if it does, report it to Facebook directly!
5. It's "JavaScript" not "Java Script" :-)

Comment: @hhh, you are welcome...I've also edited the code and added a comment above `FB.login` for those who just copy/paste the code *without* reading the full answer. ;-)