# Facebook Page has a fan or not

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to use javascript to determine if a user is a fan of a page that i've created on my account.

I found the [facebook graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api) which looks like just what i want. However it appears for some functionality i need an access token.

[Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions) it says I can just http get my /user_id/accounts page with the manage_pages permission and it will list the access token for each page.

But when i submit `https://graph.facebook.com/myuserid/accounts&scope=manage_pages` i get "OAuthException : Access token is required to request this resource."

I also tried from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088676/facebook-get-access-token), but then i get "An error occurred, please try later".

Any suggestions most welcome.

Comment: They are called "fan gates". Try googling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an access token to retrieve any information that is not public on facebook.
You can read up on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) about authenticating a user. Once your user is authenticated you can retrieve the access token and use it in your future requests (for that user)..

eg:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{YOUR_USER_ID}/accounts&access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian - yes, the `me` identifier replaces itself with the FBID if the currently logged in user. This works with all of the Facebook endpoints. For example, `graph.facebook.com/me/posts` will return your posts.