# Facebook Messanger get access token for messenger app

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

Trying to create a Facebook messenger app based on [this sample](https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples) and three values needed are:

- app secret
- page access token
- validation token

When I look up Facebook validation token I'm seeing references [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5091913/773263) one which say it is generated between your app and user name.

But according to the [code comments](https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples/blob/master/node/app.js) it is just an arbitrary value:

```
// Arbitrary value used to validate a webhook
```

Am I right to assume that this validation token is completely unrelated to the validation token described in the Javascript SDK documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access token is different from the validation token.

The validation token is an arbitrary value.

See the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/implementation) for more info.